# Inaccurate parameter uncertainties from lmfit when chi-square is close to zero

Tags: python, lmfit

It seems that the best-fit parameters reported my `lmfit` (when `scale_covar = False`) are inaccurate when chi-square is very close to zero (i.e. when the model fits the data almost perfectly). Below I perform a straight-line regression of `Y = [0,1,2]` against `X = [0,1,2]`, and add increasing amounts of noise (`f`) to the data. Only when the noise is large enough are the reported uncertainties equal to those expected from ordinary least squares.

Is this a bug/limitation in how `lmfit` estimates parameter uncertainties, or a bug/limitation in my understanding of what to expect from `lmfit`?

```py
# python 3.7.6
# lmfit 1.0.2

import numpy as np
from lmfit import minimize, Parameters

def residual(p, x, y):
    return y - (p['a'] + p['b'] * x)

def report(out):
    print(f'{f:8.0e} {out.chisqr:8.0e} {out.params["a"].value:8.2f} {out.covar[0,0]**.5:8.2f} {out.params["b"].value:8.2f} {out.covar[1,1]**.5:8.2f} {out.covar[0,1]/(out.covar[0,0]*out.covar[1,1])**.5:8.2f}')

print(f'{"noise":>8} {"chisq":>8} {"a":>8} {"SE(a)":>8} {"b":>8} {"SE(b)":>8} {"cor(a,b)":>8}')
print(f'{"-"*8} {"-"*8} {"-"*8} {"-"*8} {"-"*8} {"-"*8} {"-"*8}')

params = Parameters()
params.add('a', value=0.5)
params.add('b', value=0.5)

f = 0
X = np.array([0.,1.,2.])
Y = np.array([0.,1.,2.])
out = minimize(residual, params, args=(X, Y), scale_covar = False)
report(out)

for e in np.linspace(16,2,15):
    f = 10**-e
    Y[1] = 1 + f
    out = minimize(residual, params, args=(X, Y), scale_covar = False)
    report(out)

# OUTPUT:
# 
# 
#    noise    chisq        a    SE(a)        b    SE(b) cor(a,b)
# -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- --------
#    0e+00    2e-24     0.00     1.00     1.00     0.45    -0.00
#    1e-16    2e-24     0.00     1.00     1.00     0.45    -0.00
#    1e-15    2e-24     0.00     1.00     1.00     0.45    -0.00
#    1e-14    1e-24    -0.00     0.00     1.00     0.50    -0.45
#    1e-13    2e-24    -0.00     0.00     1.00     1.00    -0.89
#    1e-12    2e-24    -0.00     0.00     1.00     0.50    -0.45
#    1e-11    7e-23     0.00     1.00     1.00     0.45    -0.00
#    1e-10    7e-21     0.00     1.00     1.00     0.45    -0.00
#    1e-09    7e-19     0.00     1.00     1.00     0.45    -0.00
#    1e-08    7e-17     0.00     0.24     1.00     0.50    -0.44
#    1e-07    7e-15     0.00     0.93     1.00     0.67    -0.74
#    1e-06    7e-13     0.00     0.92     1.00     0.70    -0.77
#    1e-05    7e-11     0.00     0.91     1.00     0.71    -0.77
#    1e-04    7e-09     0.00     0.91     1.00     0.71    -0.77
#    1e-03    7e-07     0.00     0.91     1.00     0.71    -0.77
#    1e-02    7e-05     0.00     0.91     1.00     0.71    -0.77
```

Comment: what level of precision do you expect for these floating-point calculations?  Chi-Square should be expected to be about N (3).  Any value below that by a few orders of magnitude effectively means "0".  In Double-precision floating-point, "(number around 1) - (number around 1)" is going to be limited to a precision ~2e-16.  That's how computers represent numbers. Not a bug, not an error: an expected limitation.

Comment: Sure (NB: chisq is expected to be around 1 because there is only one degree of freedom here). But passing `method='least_squares` to `minimize()` results in a different output with the correct SE values, in spite of the floating-point precision issues you point out, implying that the `leastsq` and `least_squares` methods implement this calculation in different ways, one of which is more robust than the other. I'm not complaining that `least_squares` gets it right, but it might be worth it to have the default method use the robust calculation, or to mention this difference in the documentation.

Comment: If you're quibbling about 1 vs 3 then why is 1.e-16 important?  For reference, 1.e-16 precision would measure the distance from New York to London to the nanometer.   Worrying about (or thinking it might show a bug) whether chi-square is 1.e-10 or 1.e-20 fails to understand the meaning of the value:  It is a value of magnitude around 1 (or around N for N data points/degrees of freedom) and the 5th, let alone 10th decimal is not ever significant or meaningful.  **ALL** of the values you report for chi-square **ARE** sufficiently accurate and correct.

Comment: I'm quibbling about the variance-covariance estimates, not the chi-square values (as you well know). This discussion has obviously run its course. Have a good day.

Comment: What does "standard error" mean when chi-square is way below N/1000?

Comment: Here's an example (assuming this is a sincere question): I measure a physical property at 2 or 3 different temperatures, in a situation where analytical errors are known a priori (thus *not* estimated from chi2), and I want to model (with SE) how this property varies with T. Obviously this simple example does not require LM methods, but consider that the uncertainties in X and Y may strongly covary in complex ways, and that the fitted function may be nonlinear. In such situation estimating the SE of fit parameters is meaningful and useful (e.g. https://doi.org/10.1016/j.gsf.2018.04.001).

Comment: Well, what does "standard error" mean (and how would one calculate it) when chi-square is not  ~N, but N/1000, let alone N/1e12?  Define "standard error" in words:  "The standard error is the amount by which one changes the optimal value to increase chi-square by <some amount>"  Is that amount "1" (as would normally be the case) or is it  "N/1000"?   I don't understand how one does any sensible statistics when chi-square below ~N/10 or so.  Maybe having 3 data points and 1 degree of freedom is just not actually a robust situation.

Comment: The usual definitions apply, of course, including: "the standard error on `a` is the half-width of the projection on `a` of the joint confidence ellipse for `(a,b)` where Δχ2 < 1". What matters is the *increase* of chi2 by 1, not the actual minimum value of chi2. You can verify this is the case with the code I provided below (I suggest changing both X and Y to `[-1,0,1]` so that `a` and `b` become uncorrelated, which allows directly computing chi2 for `a = out.params["a"].value + out.covar[0,0]**.5`, etc.). Maybe we don't need to drag this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, the behavior described above changes when using the `least_squares` (Trust Region Reflective) method instead of the default `leastsq` (Levenberg-Marquardt) method, returning accurate estimates instead (see code below).

In many (most?) cases the former option will be equivalent or better than the latter in terms of convergence, with the added bonus of more robust estimates of variance-covariance in (fringe) cases such as the one described here. I'm not sure there is any obvious benefit to using `leastsq` over `least_squares`.

```py
import numpy as np
from lmfit import minimize, Parameters, __version__

def residual(p, x, y):
    return y - (p['a'] + p['b'] * x)

def report(out):
    print(f'{f:8.0e} {out.chisqr:8.0e} {out.params["a"].value:8.2f} {out.covar[0,0]**.5:8.2f} {out.params["b"].value:8.2f} {out.covar[1,1]**.5:8.2f} {out.covar[0,1]/(out.covar[0,0]*out.covar[1,1])**.5:8.2f}')

params = Parameters()
params.add('a', value=0.5)
params.add('b', value=0.5)

for method in ['least_squares', 'leastsq']:

    print(f'\nMETHOD = {method}\n')
    print(f'{"noise":>8} {"chisq":>8} {"a":>8} {"SE(a)":>8} {"b":>8} {"SE(b)":>8} {"cor(a,b)":>8}')
    print(f'{"-"*8} {"-"*8} {"-"*8} {"-"*8} {"-"*8} {"-"*8} {"-"*8}')

    f = 0
    X = np.array([0.,1.,2.])
    Y = np.array([0.,1.,2.])
    out = minimize(residual, params, args=(X, Y), scale_covar = False, method = method)
    report(out)

    for e in np.linspace(16,2,15):
        f = 10**-e
        Y[1] = 1 + f
        out = minimize(residual, params, args=(X, Y), scale_covar = False, method = method)
        report(out)

# OUTPUT:
# 
# METHOD = least_squares
# 
#    noise    chisq        a    SE(a)        b    SE(b) cor(a,b)
# -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- --------
#    0e+00    2e-32    -0.00     0.91     1.00     0.71    -0.77
#    1e-16    2e-32    -0.00     0.91     1.00     0.71    -0.77
#    1e-15    8e-31     0.00     0.91     1.00     0.71    -0.77
#    1e-14    7e-29     0.00     0.91     1.00     0.71    -0.77
#    1e-13    7e-27     0.00     0.91     1.00     0.71    -0.77
#    1e-12    7e-25     0.00     0.91     1.00     0.71    -0.77
#    1e-11    7e-23     0.00     0.91     1.00     0.71    -0.77
#    1e-10    7e-21     0.00     0.91     1.00     0.71    -0.77
#    1e-09    7e-19     0.00     0.91     1.00     0.71    -0.77
#    1e-08    7e-17     0.00     0.91     1.00     0.71    -0.77
#    1e-07    7e-15     0.00     0.91     1.00     0.71    -0.77
#    1e-06    7e-13     0.00     0.91     1.00     0.71    -0.77
#    1e-05    7e-11     0.00     0.91     1.00     0.71    -0.77
#    1e-04    7e-09     0.00     0.91     1.00     0.71    -0.77
#    1e-03    7e-07     0.00     0.91     1.00     0.71    -0.77
#    1e-02    7e-05     0.00     0.91     1.00     0.71    -0.77
# 
# METHOD = leastsq
# 
#    noise    chisq        a    SE(a)        b    SE(b) cor(a,b)
# -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- -------- --------
#    0e+00    2e-24     0.00     1.00     1.00     0.45    -0.00
#    1e-16    2e-24     0.00     1.00     1.00     0.45    -0.00
#    1e-15    2e-24     0.00     1.00     1.00     0.45    -0.00
#    1e-14    1e-24    -0.00     0.00     1.00     0.50    -0.45
#    1e-13    2e-24    -0.00     0.00     1.00     1.00    -0.89
#    1e-12    2e-24    -0.00     0.00     1.00     0.50    -0.45
#    1e-11    7e-23     0.00     1.00     1.00     0.45    -0.00
#    1e-10    7e-21     0.00     1.00     1.00     0.45    -0.00
#    1e-09    7e-19     0.00     1.00     1.00     0.45    -0.00
#    1e-08    7e-17     0.00     0.24     1.00     0.50    -0.44
#    1e-07    7e-15     0.00     0.93     1.00     0.67    -0.74
#    1e-06    7e-13     0.00     0.92     1.00     0.70    -0.77
#    1e-05    7e-11     0.00     0.91     1.00     0.71    -0.77
#    1e-04    7e-09     0.00     0.91     1.00     0.71    -0.77
#    1e-03    7e-07     0.00     0.91     1.00     0.71    -0.77
#    1e-02    7e-05     0.00     0.91     1.00     0.71    -0.77
```